# OpenCV HLS color space range

Tags: opencv, mat, hsl

Look my code, why the second line in console is `170 10 121`.

`H` is `170`, `S` is `10`, but why `L` is `121`. Because `L` must be less than `100`:

[image]

Comment: All the values are mapped between 0 and 255 :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you can see in the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?#cvtcolor)

> In case of 8-bit and 16-bit images, R, G, and B are converted to the floating-point format and scaled to fit the 0 to 1 range.
>
> If `H<0` then `H=H+360`. On output `0 <= L <= 1`, `0 <= S <= 1`, `0 <= H <= 360`.
>
> **The values are then converted to the destination data type:**
>
> - **8-bit images: S,L are scaled in [0,255], H=H/2, so H range is in [0-180]**
> - 32-bit (float) images: value are left as is.

So, in the end, for `CV_8U` images you'll have values in:

```
H in [0,180]
S,L in [0,255]
```